# How to keep pie menu in background?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an page layout which cover all components

```
const PageLayout = ({ children, navBar }) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <Container id="content">
        <MenuCricle id='menu' parrentWidth={350} menuData={donutData} childWidth={60} />
        <MenuCricle id='language' parrentWidth={140} menuData={languageData} childWidth={20} />
        {children}
      </Container>
      <Footer>
        <div className="text-center">&copy; 2017. {settings.app.name}.</div>
      </Footer>
    </section>
  );
};
```

And each page have prototype look like this

```
class SecuritySystemPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <PageLayout>
       {//some thing to display here}
      </PageLayout>
    )
  }
}
```

Result I got when use `PageLayout` above is:
[image: failed]
But my expect result is:
[image]

Is there any way to reach my expect result? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have to write CSS for each element.

Comment: @Sam Can you give me an example for some case like this?

Comment: For example: #menu { position: absolute; right: 200px; top: 50% } Something like this.

Comment: Absolute positioning might place it on the right but you won't get the wrapping effect you expect on the other hand the text will just ignore that image and hide behind it like nothing's there. You need to float it using float:right.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demonstration of how the output appears when `float:right` is added.

- The neighboring elements wrap around the content which is floated.
- You can add a margin to the floated element to make space around it.

```css
.circle{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:blue;
border:5px solid darkblue;
border-radius:50%;
float:right;
margin:15px;
}
```

```html
<p>This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works </p>

<p>This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works </p>

<div class="circle"></div>

<p>This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works </p>

<p>This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works </p>

<p>This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works This is random content to show you how float right works </p>
```